# Match only if word is contained within constraints, Regex

Tags: regex

I am struggling with finding the regex to find a word that must be between two others.

in simple, my constraints are:

- must begin with the word `line con`
- must end with the next appearence of the word `line`
- between these two must have the word `session-timeout`
- may also contain other words between `line con` and `line`.

I wish to match on any block of text starting with `line con` and ending with the next instance of the word `line`, however I need them to only match if the word `session-timeout` is between them.

bonus points if you can tell me how to match for any number larger than 10 after `session-timeout` (eg. `session-timeout 12` would match)

an example of where I would want it to match is:

```
line con 0
session-timeout 14
stopbits 1
line aux 0
stopbits 1
line vty 0 4
```

However, this should not match

```
line con 0
session-timeout 8
stopbits 1
line aux 0
stopbits 1
line vty 0 4
session-timeout 13
line vty 0 5
```

so far I have the regex expression `(line con)(\s|\S)+?(session-timeout ){1}([0-9])(\s|\S)+?(line)`, however if it does not match a `session-timeout` within the terms, it simply ignores the first `line`, which is where I want it to stop looking.

Any help would be massivley appreciated!

Comment: Try: `line con[\s\S]+?session-timeout [0-9]{2,}[\s\S]+?lineline con[\s\S]+?session-timeout [0-9]{2,}[\s\S]+?line`

Comment: @anubhava doubled regex? If not `[1-9][0-9]+` why not just `\d\d` (rest are caught by the following `\S+`)?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/wSnbHz/1

Comment: why should the second data not match?

Comment: @D-E-N, The second should not match, as the only `session-timeout` within the `line con` and `line` block is followed by a number less than 11, and the `session-timeout` with the value 13 is outside of the `line con`, `line` block.

Comment: @jhnc: Sorry double copy/paste :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
(line con)(?:(?!line con)[\s\S])+?(session-timeout\s+)([1-9][0-9]+)[\s\S]+?(line)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/shW0xO/1). Details:

- `(line con)` - Group 1: `line con` string
- `(?:(?!line con)[\s\S])+?` - any char, one or more occurrences but as few as possible, that does not start `line con` char sequence
- `(session-timeout\s+)` - Group 2: `session-timeout` string and one or more whitespaces
- `([1-9][0-9]+)` - Group 3: a number from `10` and larger (if you want to allow any leading zeros, append `0*` before `[1-9]`)
- `[\s\S]+?` - any one or more chars, as few as possible
- `(line)` - Group 4: `line`.

Adjust the capturing groups as per your requirements.